# Change background transparency of Chart.js chart

Tags: ionic-framework, chart.js, angular-chart

i'm using chart.js wrapped within [angular-charts.js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) to create a bar chart in an Ionic framework app.

I want to make the bar background totally opaque.

This the code i have to create the chart.

```
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" data="data" labels="labels" legend="true" series="series" options="{showTooltips: false}" colours="[ '#ffff00',    '#0066ff']"></canvas>
```

Have any idea of how could i achieve that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Add a opacity class for your div container as <div class="char-container" style="opacity:0.5">, if it will not work means add a css class as .fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)"; and implement that class in your project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`colours` should be an array of color objects (not an array of color strings). So you need `[ { fillColor: '#ffff00' }, { fillColor: '#0066ff' } ]`

```html
<canvas
    id="bar"
    class="chart chart-bar"
    data="data"
    labels="labels"
    legend="true"
    series="series"
    options="{showTooltips: false}"
    colours="[ { fillColor: '#ffff00' }, { fillColor: '#0066ff' } ]"
    ></canvas>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dyt0wf31/

Comment: If you would like to have a desired transparency you can use the rgba color format like this `"[ { fillColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.6)' }, { fillColor: 'rgba(0,102,255,0.6)' } ]"`